# windows 7 USB boot disk wont read

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7, uefi

I have been trying with numerous methods to install Windows 7 alongside my 14.04 Ubuntu installation (64bit) which has a UEFI boot system, but none of the methods have worked yet.Here are some of the methods oI have tried:

1 - I made a bootable USB using the [Windows7 USB-DVD tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool) on a Windows machine (everything seemed to work fine during creation), but when I go to load it, my machine boots right into ubuntu. I then went into GParted on Ubuntu and assigned a BOOT flag to the USB drive, but this didnt help. Windows installer just wont boot.

2 - I also tried using [Unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/) from my Mac machine, and all seemed well during the creation of the installer, but that would not boot either.

3 - I have also tried using [WinUSB](http://en.congelli.eu/prog_info_winusb.html) for Ubuntu, however I am getting a 512 error.
While researching this error I read that *"WinUSB only creates MBR bootable USB drives. If you want to install Windows in EFI mode a different method should be used".*

Comment: Use Windows and Use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comments, use Rufus on Windows and it will work like a charm.

Comment: there was a major issue with this, that being that RUFUS would not let me choose MBR, so I was forced to use GPT which is different form my UEFI, and caused all kinds of havok with booting to windows. I was able to install Windows, but not able to get it to boot without having to have a USB stick attached.

Comment: You can also try using Etcher at etcher.io which is dead simple and might work for you.